# Replicating `\SetKwInOut` and the format from `algorithm2e` in `algorithmicx`

Tags: formatting, algorithms, algorithmicx

## Brief

I've heard that `algorithmicx` is the best algorithm package to use. However, in my work I've been using `algorithm2e`. On looking at a few examples on here its clear that it is a bit difficult converting between the two.

In particular, I've notice that the `\SetKwInOut`commands do not exist in `algorithmicx`. For example:

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

%for original algorithm 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

%\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

%Original table to try and replicate

\lipsum[1-1] 


\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \SetKwInOut{Define}{Define}
    \underline{Initialise:} Conditions for algorithm\;
    \Define {Definition of algorithm}
    \Input{Input of Algorithm} 
    \Output{Output of algorithm}

    \underline{Sequence In Full:} 

      {

       \hspace{5pt}  \textbf{Start}: 

      }
      {

       \hspace{17pt}  Step 1  \;

      }
      {


        \bgroup\leftskip 15pt \hspace{1pt}  \lipsum[1-1] \; \par\egroup

      }

      {

       \hspace{17pt}  Step 2  \;

      }
      {


        \bgroup\leftskip 15pt \hspace{1pt}  \lipsum[1-1] \; \par\egroup

      }
      {

       \hspace{17pt}  Step 3  \;

      }
      {

      \hspace {5pt} \textbf{End}

      }

    \caption{Name of algorithm}\label{alg:Name} 
\end{algorithm} 



\end{document}
```

[image]

## Goal

Is there any way to replicate the above into `algorithmicx`. (As you can see the reason as to why i want to convert it is because i've read that `algorithmicx`is the only package which allows you to separate the algorithm over multiple pages). Thank-you in advance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes `algorithmicx` has something like: `\SetKwInOut` it's called : `\Require` and `\Ensure` in the `algopseudocode` layout of `algorithmicx` (you will have to use \usepcakage{algopseudocode}`).

Then you can rename it as you want using this methods:

```
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}
```

as suggested here: [Align Input and Output of algorithm to left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353132/align-input-and-output-of-algorithm-to-left)