# How to insert mathcal symbol in lstlisting environment in beamer?

Tags: beamer, mathcal

[image]

I want to type the above algorithm in beamer block, but I stuck inserting `mathcal symbols`. I tried `$\mathcal{Q}$` and `\mathcal{Q}`, but both are failed to return expected symbol.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\lstset{language=Python}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{block}{Algorithm}
\begin{lstlisting}
$\mathcal{Q}$
  for i in range(10):
      foo(arg1, arg2)
  bar = qux()
\end{lstlisting}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%this code is from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353165/101651
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}%
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{block}{Algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}
      Input: $\mathcal{Q}_{\text{init}}$, \mathcal{A}, and \textit{f}(c).
    Initialize: Obtain \writetilde{c_{i}} by solving frac{\delta f(c)}{\delta c_{i}}=0, for i\in\mathcal{N}.Set k = 1, \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{Q}_{init},\mathcal{u}_{i}=\gamma_{ub}(\mathcal{Q}_{init} and \mathcal{l}_{1} = \gamma_\left\{ lb}(\]mathcal{Q}_{init}.
      Check the feasibility of problem (17) with given \writetilde{c}.
      if feasible then
      c_{0} = \writetilde{c};
      else
      while u_{k} - l_{k} > \epsilon do
      Branching:
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Set \mathcal{Q}_{k} = \mathcal{Q}, where \mathcal{Q} satisfies \gamma_\left\{ lb}(\mathcal{Q} = l_{k}.
          \item Split \mathcal{Q} into \mathcal{Q}_{\rm{I}} and \mathcal{Q}_{\rm{II}}, along one of its longest edges.
          \item Update \mathcal{B}_{k+1} = (\mathcal{B}_{k}\{\mathcal{Q}_{k}}) \union (\mathcal{Q}_{\rm{I}}, \mathcal{Q}_{\rm{II}}.
      \end{itemize}
      Bounding:
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Update \mathcal{u}_{k+1} = \min_{\mathcal{Q}\in\mathcal{B}_{k+1}{\gamma_{ub}(\mathcal{Q})}
        \item Update \mathcal{l}_{k+1} = \min_{\mathcal{Q}\in\mathcal{B}_{k+1}{\gamma_{lb}(\mathcal{Q})}
      \end{itemize}
      Set k=k+1;
      end while
      Set c_{0} = c_{min};
      end if
      Output: c_{0}.
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I typed the above Algorithm with numerous errors. I typed this type of algorithm in LaTeX at first. So, if some one give me the expected code editing this code to get the result like this algorithm, then it is very helpful to me.

Comment: Your code is a listing but your image is an algorithm, see here: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yes, you are right.

Comment: @CarLaTeX You can give a answer with your assumption.

Comment: @alhelal I noticed you edited your question to add another question. I suggest that you post a new question, instead. Since nobody is notified about edits very few people will see it, and it will probably remain unanswered. I looked quickly at your code and the major problem is that you are using math-mode commands outside of math mode. You will solve most of them by adding a few `$...$` here and there.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you for your recommendation. I asked a new question.https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416471/how-to-show-algorithm-in-beamer-slide, Now, should I remove the edited portion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that it is a verbatim environment, so *everything* is verbatim. To make it *not* verbatim you have to use the option `escapeinside`:

```
\lstset{escapeinside={@(}{)@}}
```

so that any code between `@(...)@` is escaped back to LaTeX.

Best practice is to use more than one character for escaping to avoid ambiguity. Also try to choose a combination that will not appear in your code. In python, for example, using `:(...):` would be a bad idea because of the syntax of the `for` loop.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\lstset{language=Python}
\lstset{escapeinside={@(}{)@}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{block}{Algorithm}
\begin{lstlisting}
@($\mathcal{Q}$)@
  for i in range(10):
      foo(arg1, arg2)
  bar = qux()
\end{lstlisting}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like your answer, but if I want to insert `@text@`?

Comment: The same rules apply. whatever is inside `@@` will be parsed by LaTeX. If you give it `@text@`, then the contents of `text` will be parsed by normal LaTeX, not in a verbatim context. Note that in my answer I open math mode with `$$` inside the `@@`.

Comment: You don't understand me. I want to get `@text@` as output.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then you have to change the value of `escapeinside`. Actually, best practice is to use more than one character for escaping, and choose something that you'll not have in your listing. I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: what is the symbol in 2nd line of my algorithm image (u_1, l_1). I can't make these symbol in latex.

Comment: @alhelal That is a greek letter `\gamma` (γ). You can use [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org) to look for symbols you don't know :). On a side note, there are two answers here that solve your problem. Please mark one of them as accepted.

Comment: I didn't find that in detexify.

Comment: Well, [it's there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wESO6.png)...

Comment: I don't tell for gamma, I tell for `u_1`

Comment: @alhelal Well, `u_1` is just `u_1`. Type `$u_1$` in LaTeX and you will get that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73535/discussion-between-alhelal-and-phelype-oleinik).

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP would like to see an example of an algorithm...

The code for `\Input` comes from [an answer of gernot's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353165/101651).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%this code is from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353165/101651
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}%
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{block}{Algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \Input $\mathcal{Q}_{\text{inn}}$
            \For{$i=0$ to $10$}
            \State do something with arg1 and arg2
            \State $bar \leftarrow qux()$
            \EndFor
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]