# How could I use While command in this case

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I am trying to write algorithm. However, I cannot use `\While` command as I got an error saying that, `some blocks are not closing.` I really do not know how to fix this problem. Any help, please?

Here is the code I used. **Please note that, I toked this example from this site. [Align Input and Output of algorithm to left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353132/align-input-and-output-of-algorithm-to-left/353165?newreg=7fcfa732eff342a488b582a834bf62df).

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Dsfdgfgskj sdfgfkjsdl sdfggjlkj fgsdt}
        \label{alg:ALG1}
        \begin{algorithmic}
        \Require $x$ - decision tree
        \Ensure $abc$ is $x$ in Txx Bxxxxx Gxxxx
```

**I would like to use `\While` command here. Like this:**

```
\While{(not converged \& i < maximum number of iteration)}{
            \Function {UpdateNodes}{$x$}
                \If {  $wrejkwe$ ($rw$) trwer tewwerl }
                %       \COMMENT { 
                \State {jklrjkljfgkljlkj  kjkldfj gfdsdf }
                \State  Set fdgsdsd
                \ForAll  {$j=1$ to $N (x)$}
                \State        Call $fgsd(x)$  
                \State        Set $sfgdfgd =sfdg + fgds $ 

                \EndFor 
                \EndIf
            \EndFunction

}##end of While. 

            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

I got an error when I try to use `\While` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove any `#` (`%` is for comments), place `<` in math mode and end the while loop with `\EndWhile`.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Dsfdgfgskj sdfgfkjsdl sdfggjlkj fgsdt}
        \label{alg:ALG1}
        \begin{algorithmic}
        \Require $x$ - decision tree
        \Ensure $abc$ is $x$ in Txx Bxxxxx Gxxxx
                \While{(not converged \& $i < \text{maximum number of iteration}$)}
            \Function {UpdateNodes}{$x$}
                \If {  $wrejkwe$ ($rw$) trwer tewwerl }
                %       \COMMENT { 
                \State {jklrjkljfgkljlkj  kjkldfj gfdsdf }
                \State  Set fdgsdsd
                \ForAll  {$j=1$ to $N (x)$}
                \State        Call $fgsd(x)$  
                \State        Set $sfgdfgd =sfdg + fgds $ 

                \EndFor 
                \EndIf
            \EndFunction
                \EndWhile
         \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```